# Create a parquet file from CSV represented as string using duckdb

Tags: duckdb

Given the following:

```py
import io
buffer = io.BytesIO()
csv_data = 'col1,col2\n1,2\n3,4`
```

I want to know how I can use duckdb ( https://duckdb.org/docs/data/parquet/overview.html ) to write a parquet file to the `buffer` in memory, where file will contain the column/row data from the `csv_data` variable.

I'm using duckdb version `0.7.1` (I'm not fixed to this version though).

## edit

Suggested to try the following:

```py
import duckdb
from io import BytesIO
csv_data = BytesIO(b'col1,col2\n1,2\n3,4')
duckdb.read_csv(csv_data, header=True).write_parquet('csv_data.parquet')
```

Which failed with:

```
In [1]: import duckdb

In [2]: from io import BytesIO
   ...:

In [3]: csv_data = BytesIO(b'col1,col2\n1,2\n3,4')
   ...:

In [4]: duckdb.read_csv(csv_data, header=True).write_parquet('csv_data.parquet')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 1
----> 1 duckdb.read_csv(csv_data, header=True).write_parquet('csv_data.parquet')

TypeError: read_csv(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (name: str, connection: duckdb.DuckDBPyConnection = None, header: object = None, compression: object = None, sep: object = None, delimiter: object = None, dtype: object = None, na_values: object = None, skiprows: object = None, quotechar: object = None, escapechar: object = None, encoding: object = None, parallel: object = None, date_format: object = None, timestamp_format: object = None, sample_size: object = None, all_varchar: object = None, normalize_names: object = None, filename: object = None) -> duckdb.DuckDBPyRelation

Invoked with: <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f21ed64d620>; kwargs: header=True
```

Comment: This works in `0.8.0`

Comment: @jqurious thanks - I can confirm that this works in `0.8.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read it with `read_csv` and write it to parquet with `write_parquet`

```py
import duckdb
from io import BytesIO
csv_data = BytesIO(b'col1,col2\n1,2\n3,4')
duckdb.read_csv(csv_data, header=True).write_parquet('csv_data.parquet')
```

Note - this does not work on version `0.7.1`, but does work on `0.8.0`

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work - I'll update the OP with the error I got from that